# Как сделать обработку longpoll vk api на php?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, long-poll

Через

```
    file_get_contents()
```

идет получение данных longpoll`a. В python библиотеке vk_api есть такая реализация получения событий

```py
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
   #Слушаем longpoll, если пришло сообщение то:         
        if event.text == 'Первый вариант фразы' or event.text == 'Второй вариант фразы': #Если написали заданную фразу
...
```

Как лучше реализовать получения событий на php? Пока в голову идет только что-то похожее на реализацию обработки вебсокетов из библы для php

```php
$io = new SocketIO(2021);
$io->on('connection', function($socket)use($io){
  $socket->on('chat message', function($msg)use($io){
    $io->emit('chat message', $msg);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

В итоге самый адекватный вариант получился, именно используя замыкания

```php
$vk = simplevk();
$vk->listen(function($data)use($vk){
  print_r($data);
});
```